# Turbo Table : can't select row by clicking on checkbox

Tags: angular, primeng

I have once scenario with table. Supposed to have multiple selection mode with Checkbox selection in Table.

Not able to select row by clicking on checkbox which is in first column of Table.

I can select row by clicking on row, but not by checkbox.

Please find Demo here - [PrimeNg-Turbo Table Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table)

Answer (score 0):

remove "selectionMode" attribute from "p-table" tag.

Comment: Supposed to have multiple selection mode with Checkbox selection in Table.

Comment: @AbhijitMuke You cannot have both "selectionMode=multiple" and [pSelectableRow]="rowData" [pSelectableRowIndex]="rowIndex"  which is "select row by clicking anywhere in it". These two options are mutually exclusive.